# Python Graph: How to find all possible path between source and target nodes

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I need to generate all possible combinations of paths between source and destination nodes. The technique which i am using is backtracking like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-two-vertices/

The issue i am getting is that i am receiving only on path. While there are other too. My graph data is graphData = {1: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdAyB.png), 2: [3], 3: [4], 4: [2, 5], 5: [6, 7], 6: [3], 7: [8], 8: [9], 9: [10]}

[image: my graph look like this]
[image]

It is giving me only one path which is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10] while others not.
The total required paths are

- P1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
- P2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8,
  9, 10]
- P3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
- P4 = [1, 2, 3,
  4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 , 10]

What i am missing any idea or solution for this problem.

Current Code

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph:

def __init__(self, vertices):
    self.V = vertices
    self.graph = defaultdict(list)

def addEdge(self, u, v):
    self.graph[u].append(v)


def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path): 

    # Mark the current node as visited and store in path 
    visited[u]= True
    path.append(u) 

    # If current vertex is same as destination, then print 
    # current path[] 
    if u ==d: 
        print (path )
    else: 
        # If current vertex is not destination 
        #Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
        for i in self.graph[u]: 
            if visited[i]==False: 
                self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path) 

    # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited 
    path.pop() 
    visited[u]= False

# Prints all paths from 's' to 'd' 
def printAllPaths(self,s, d): 

    # Mark all the vertices as not visited 
    visited =[False]*(self.V) 

    # Create an array to store paths 
    path = [] 

    # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths 
    self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d,visited, path) 


graphData = {1: [2], 2: [3], 3: [4], 4: [2, 5],5: [6, 7], 6: [3], 7: [8], 8: [9], 9: [10]}

g = Graph(10)
for item in graphData:
    for itemx in graphData[item]:
        g.addEdge(int(item), int(itemx))
s = 1
d = 9
g.printAllPaths(s, d)
```

Comment: Can you show some code for what you've tried?  From the images and description, it's unclear whether your graph is directed or not.  Your hand-drawn graph looks directed while your solution and networkx plotted graph are for the undirected case. Is it supposed to be directed or undirected?

Comment: the graph is to be directed

Comment: I have added the current code in the main question